# Why I cannot get the correct number of candies using this program?

Tags: java

This exercise required us to write a program for counting the number of candies the poor kids can get. The question is shown below:

*You are requested to write a Java program to help these poor kids to answer this question. To generalize the solution, your program should be able to accept different values of n and m as input, where n = 10 and m = 2 in this question. To avoid infinite number of answers, you may assume that each candy has exactly one foil and it is not allowed to cut the foils.*

And I follow the hints given to write the program using the provided formula and java recursion.

[image]

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyFirstClass{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner a=new Scanner(System.in);
        int n=0,m=0;
        n = a.nextInt();
        m = a.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Candy " +n+" "+ m + " n="+ n+";m="+m+";No. of Candies="+total(n,m));
    }
    static int sum=0;
     static int total(int n, int m)
     {
         int sum1=n;
         sum1+=candy(n,m);
         return sum1;
     }
     static int candy(int n,int m){
        if((n+n%m)/m>1){
            sum+=n/m+candy((n+(n%m))/m,m);
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

However, when I set n=10 and m=2, the calculated total number of candies is less than the actual total number of candies by 1. What is the problem of my program? Thank you!

Comment: This is a good time to start learning how to use a debugger.

Comment: Could you help us understanding your formulas? Please explain them. What exactly is happening there? Else we need some time to get into it and many are not willing to do this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your candy function:

```
 static int candy(int n,int m){
    if((n+n%m)/m>1){
        sum+=n/m+candy((n+(n%m))/m,m);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

How does it even compile when `sum` is undefined?

In any case, the `candy` function needs to check the boundary condition of of when the first paramater is 0 or 1. And I'll assume negative numbers aren't valid input either.

```
int candy(int n, int m) {
    if ((n <= 1) || (m == 0)) {
        return 0;
    }
    return n/m + candy( ((n+n%m)/m), m);
}
```

And since it's "tail recursion", you can implement the entire thing with a while loop:

```
int candy(int n, int m) {

    int result = 0;

    while ((n > 1) && (m != 0))
    {
        result += n/m;
        n = (n+n%m)/m;
    }

    return result;
}
```